# Error compiling assets after upgrading bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4, sass, bootstrap-ui

I'm trying to upgrade the bootstrap version in a Ruby on Rails application. After migratinng from `4.0.0-alpha.6` to `4.1` using yarn I get this error when running `rails assets:precompile`

#### error

```
SassC::SyntaxError: Error: Undefined variable: "$alert-warning-bg".
        on line 32:20 of app/assets/stylesheets/variables/_helpers.scss
        from line 47:9 of app/assets/stylesheets/variables.scss
        from line 9:9 of app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss
        from line 1:9 of app/assets/stylesheets/admin.scss
>>   outline: lighten($alert-warning-bg, 9%);
```

#### helper.scss

```
.highlight {
  outline: lighten($alert-warning-bg, 9%);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$alert-warning-bg` was removed on `4.1` and replaced with `theme-color-level($color, $alert-bg-level)` mixin (to make it DRY?). usage example:

```
theme-color-level('warning', $alert-bg-level)
```

or specifically on your case:

```
lighten(theme-color-level('warning', $alert-bg-level), 9%)
```